# Meteor: Best way to implement post categories

Tags: meteor

I'm working on creating a simple CMS where users can create a blog and add categories. I currently have a 'posts' collection and a 'categories' collection. It works perfectly the way I have it coded, but it seems like I had to write a lot of code to get it to work. See below for the functionality:

display_posts.html

```
<template name="displayPostAdmin">
...
<ul class="category-choices">
    {{#each categories}}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="category-{{name}}" class="category-option" value="{{name}}" {{isChecked ../categories}}/>
            <label class="label inline" for="category-{{name}}">{{name}}</label>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
...
</template>
```

So this is iterating through the categories collection and creating a new checkbox for each category. This is pretty standard. Please note the {{isChecked ../categories}}, which calls an 'isChecked' helper function which gets the post categories (../categories) passed to it. See below for the template javascript

display_posts.js

```
Template.displayPostAdmin.helpers({
...
isChecked: function(categories){
    if (categories){
        for (var i=0; i<categories.length; i++){
            if (this.name == categories[i])
                return 'checked';
        }
    }
}
```

The isChecked helper function get passed an array of categories that are stored in the 'Posts' collection. The function iterates through the array using a for loop and will return a 'checked' string if this.name (the name of the category per the Category collection) is equal to any of the items in the passed array. I want it to returned 'checked' so that when a user pulls up the edit post page, any categories that were assigned to the post show up as already checked.

My question: is there a more efficient way of doing this that I am missing?

Comment: There are a couple of packages on atmosphere that allow you to reactively join collections and iterate as though there is a single document. The latest one seems to be https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/smart-publish and there are others if you search for keywords such as publish join reactive Using such a package will simplify your code. Would this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - though the package you linked to says it isn't production ready so I'll have to look elsewhere, though I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: I know there are a number of people using it with success. Meteor itself is not 1.0 yet if that's a concern :) You can also check out https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/publish-composite https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reactive-publish and https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/publish-with-relations